# Firebase-firestore can't use two documents

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm starting to mess around with `firestore` and I'm having one problem:

When I add a second document to my `collection`, the `spinner` I have stops loading the information and the **app crashes**.

```
db.collection("KitList").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            val data = document.data
            val skipRope = data["rope"] as String

            spinnerArray.add(skipRope)

            val kettle = data["kettle"] as ArrayList<String>
            for (item in kettle) {
                val kettleWeight = "kettle $item"
                spinnerArray.add(kettleWeight)
            }
        }
        spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

I know, most likely it is because on my code I'm only setting up the load to be from my collection, but I tried to do something like

```
`db.collection("KitList").document(documentName).get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->`
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Anyone knows? :)

Comment: provide output error.

Comment: I get an error in "for (document in snapshot.documents)": unresolved reference documents

Comment: Have you tried to call the original Java beans method `getDocuments()`?

Comment: I am using Kotlin. The equivalent for both get/set is what I have

Comment: I know. but you can still use getter/setter methods. provide the error stacktrace for more information.

Comment: if I do that I get error on the get instead. (unresolved)

Comment: No one, really? :/